# Stable set by intersection and by finite union

Tags: probability, measure-theory

i'm reading a classical book in measure theory, and there is something i don't get. I would say it is a missprint but since the book is famous, probably there is something i don't get, and i need some other opinion.

They claim the following in one of their proofs : Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a set of subsets of a set $E$ so that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{E}$, and denote $\mathcal{E}'$ the smallest set of subsets of $E$ among those which contain $\mathcal{E}$ and are stable by finite union and by any intersection.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the smallest set of subsets of $E$ among those which contain $\mathcal{E}$ and are stable by finite union. Then $\mathcal{E}'$ is the smallest set of subsets of $E$ among those which contain $\mathcal{F}$ and are stable by any intersection.

Do you agree that this claim is clearly wrong or do i miss something ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you think that it is *"clearly wrong"*, why don't you add a counter-example to your question? – A concrete reference to the book and the proof would also be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that taking intersections of finite unions, we obtain a family which is stable by intersection, but which does not seem to be stable by finite unions. I would say we should rather take finite unions of intersections of elements of $\mathcal{E}$

Comment: This question becomes easier (for me) and might already be familiar to you if reformulated in terms of the complements of the sets. It then says that if $\mathcal X$ is a subbase for a topology $\mathcal T$) (i.e., $\mathcal T$ is the smallest topology that includes $\mathcal X$), then one can obtain $\mathcal T$ by first closing $\mathcal X$ under finite intersections to obtain a base for $\mathcal T$ and then closing that base under arbitrary unions.

Answer (score 1):

Call $$\Sigma = \{ X \subseteq E: \mathcal{E} \subseteq X, \mbox{ stable under finite unions and all intersections}\}$$
$$\Omega = \{ X \subseteq E: \mathcal{E} \subseteq X, \mbox{ stable under finite unions}\}$$
then clearly $\Sigma \subseteq \Omega$, so
$$\mathcal{F} = \bigcap \Omega \subseteq \bigcap \Sigma = \mathcal{E}'$$
Moreover, $\mathcal{E}'$ is stable under finite unions and all intersections, and contains $\mathcal{F}$.

Now, let $Y$ be stable under finite unions and all intersections, and containing $\mathcal{F}$. We need to show that $Y$ contains $\mathcal{E}'$.

But now, $\mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathcal{F} \subseteq Y$, so $Y \in \Sigma$. This implies that $\mathcal{E}' \subseteq Y$.

Comment: Problem here is, you don't have that $Y$ is stable under finite union, only that it is stable under intersections.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, but I needed some time to see it aswell.
Let $S$ be the smallest set containing $\mathcal{F}$ which is stable by any intersection. We claim that $S$ is then stable by finite union which proves the statement.

Of course it suffices to show, that for $A,B\in S$ we have $A\cup B\in S$.

Let $A,B\in S$. Then there exist $A_i,B_j \in \mathcal{F}$ with $i\in I, j\in J$, s.t. $A = \bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$ and $\bigcap_{j\in J} B_j = B$. This is by minimality of $S$.

Now we have $\displaystyle A\cup B = \left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)\cup \left(\bigcap_{j\in J}B_j\right) = \bigcap_{i\in I,j\in J} (A_i\cup B_j)$.

Since $A_i,B_j\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is stable by finite unions we have $A_i\cup B_j\in\mathcal{F}$ for all $i,j$, hence have $A\cup B\in S$ as intersection of sets in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: The question is about arbitrary intersections, not just finite intersections. Fortunately, the proof works equally well in the general case. The crucial point is the distributive law $\big(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\big)\cup\big(\bigcap_{j\in J}B_j\big)=\bigcap_{i\in I, j\in J}(A_i\cup B_j)$, which holds regardless of how big $I$ and $J$ are.

Comment: True, I saw finite unions and then assumed that intersections had to be finite aswell. Going to edit my post. Thanks for your comment.